# Can not connect to internet in VirtualBox VM - Ubuntu

Tags: networking, virtualbox, internet

I've installed Ubuntu on a VM in VirtualBox and created 2 clones from that. Everything was fine but after a while my internet connections failed in all of VMs in VirtualBox.

Followings are Network settings:

- Bridged Adapter
- Allow all(i also check allow vms)
- Cable connected

Even though I change the MAC address to the same one of my Windows host, it still doesn't work.

Can u help me?

Comment: You should NOT change the Mac address to the same as the host, that is (mostly) always wrong. What is the output of 'ip add', 'ip route', 'ping 8.8.8.8' and 'tracepath 8.8.8.8'? Yes, removing the udev file could be needed on a clone, also host keys for ssh server if you have sshd installed. There are some other stuff like that which is needed on clones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are `udev` rules preventing the new interface from being brought up.

In the original VM, launch the Terminal (press the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and enter following command before cloning the new VMs:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

Comment: You should do that on the clone, not the original. There are other things also needed to be done on clones.